# If Statement based on Visibility JS Fade In

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I change this so nothing happens if the element being faded in is already visibility = 'visible' It's basically changing visibility based on mouse position, but right now it fades in every time the mouse moves. Demo: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/246684898/VipSitaraman.com/index2.htm. If you're bored, feel free to steal my code cuz coding it was a pain and I'd love to help someone else...just credit me.

```
$(".txt").mousemove(function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var a = e.clientX - offset.left;
    var b = e.clientY - offset.top;
    var c = 0
    if (a > 0 && a <= 750) {
        $('#s1').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();
            $('#s2,#s3,#s4,#s5,#s6').css('visibility','hidden');
            $('#home').text(c + ", "+ b);
        } else if (a > 750 && a <= 1500) {
            $('#s2').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();
            $('#s1,#s3,#s4,#s5,#s6').css('visibility','hidden');
        } else if (a > 1500 && a <= 2250) {
            $('#s3').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();
            $('#s1,#s2,#s4,#s5,#s6').css('visibility','hidden');
        } else if (a > 2250 && a <= 3000) {
            $('#s4').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();
            $('#s1,#s2,#s3,#s5,#s6').css('visibility','hidden');
        } else if (a > 3000 && a <= 3750) {
            $('#s5').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();
            $('#s1,#s2,#s3,#s4,#s6').css('visibility','hidden');
        } else if (a > 3750 && a <= 4500) {
            $('#s6').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();
            $('#s1,#s2,#s3,#s5,#s4').css('visibility','hidden');
        } else {
            $('#s1,#s2,#s3,#s5,#s4,#s6').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5u2SR/2/ ?

Comment: i think so except for each selector (#s1 through #s6) it needs to not fade in again if i hover on it again. so i was thinking it would be an addition to each if statement but idk what

Comment: Initially whether all s1..6 will be visible or hidden

Comment: also see a cleaned up version of previous code http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5u2SR/3/

Comment: initially they're all hidden. does that help? on the demo i linked, you can mouseover practically anywhere on the picture part of the website and stuff pops up (there are 6 of them; s1-s6)

Comment: can you edit the attached fiddle to recreate your case?... your attached demo is not working.. is it hidden using `display:none` or `visibility: hidden`

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5u2SR/4/

Comment: something about the use of .data is screwing it up. otherwise it works.

Comment: got it! turns out your 2nd fiddle works but the later one doesn't but idk and idrc why thank youuuuu!

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5u2SR/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var $ss = $('.s');
$(".txt").mousemove(function (e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var a = e.clientX - offset.left;
    var b = e.clientY - offset.top;
    var c = 0;
    var d = Math.ceil(a / 750);
    if (d > 0 && d <= $ss.length) {
        var $t = $ss.eq(d - 1);
        if (!$t.data('visible')) {
            $t.css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn().data('visible', true);
            $ss.not($t).css('visibility', 'hidden').data('visible', false);
            $('#home').text(c + ", " + b);
        }
    } else {
        $ss.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5u2SR/7/)